# XPathException: Values of 'standalone' and 'omit-xml-declaration' conflict

Tags: java, xslt, transform, docx

Добрый день! Я использую xslt преобразование для конвертации docx файла в html. 
и получаю следующую ошибку

```
XPathException: Values of 'standalone' and 'omit-xml-declaration' conflict
```

Предпологается, что **.docх** файл уже разархивирован. Для формирования html я обрабатываю файл word/document.xml

```
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource xslStream = new StreamSource("DocX2Html.xsl");
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslStream);
    StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource("1/word/document.xml");
    StreamResult out = new StreamResult("out.html");
    transformer.transform(streamSource, out);
```

[Файл xslt](http://spindocs.spinboxmedia.co.uk/TransformSheets/DocX2Html.xsl)

Подробнее об ошибке:

```
Error on line 6515 of DocX2Html.xsl:
SEPM0009: Values of 'standalone' and 'omit-xml-declaration' conflict
at xsl:apply-templates (file:///C:/Users/Administrator/IdeaProjects/docx-xslx-to-html/DocX2Html.xsl#6617)
 processing /w:document
Exception in thread "main" ; SystemID: file:///C:/Users/Administrator/IdeaProjects/docx-xslx-to-html/DocX2Html.xsl; Line#: 6515; Column#: -1
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Values of 'standalone' and 'omit-xml-declaration' conflict
```

Я не совсем понимаю, почему возникает такая ошибка?